# Filter BLE UART communications from Android HCI BT Snoop log in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, bluetooth

I managed to log BLE communications with a Nordic chip based device I am interested in on my Android phone and loaded the log in Wireshark, applying `btatt` as filter.

It uses some default BLE "transmissions" like "Battery Service: Battery Level" as well as UART for actual control. Wiresharks Info column shows e.g.:

```
Sent Write Request, Handle: 0x0011 (Nordic UART Service: Nordic UART Tx)
...
Rcvd Handle Value Notification, Handle: 0x000e (Nordic UART Service: Nordic UART Rx)
```

How can I set a filter to get only the UART Rx and Tx raw data as a list?

Answer (score 0):

"Apply / Prepare as Filter" context menu gives some hints:

```
btgatt.nordic.uart_rx or btgatt.nordic.uart_tx
```

I'm sure there is an option to export the raw data of the result rows somehow.